# Which exchanges are Tor-friendly?

Tags: exchanges, mtgox, privacy, tor, aml

Mt. Gox's sign-up page states:

> Please be advised that accessing your account via the Tor network
>   and/or public proxies may result in a temporary suspension of your
>   account, and having to submit AML documents.

Are there other exchanges which do not have such a restriction (e.g. for transfers and account balances below $1K USD for instance?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BitInstant seems like a nice Tor-friendly option (they even accept deposits in cash): https://www.bitinstant.com/

Comment: +1 though it's not _exactly_ an exchange, unless I'm mistaken

Answer (score 1):

Cryptsy is TOR friendly- allowing users to both access the site and maintain accounts via TOR. This is as of 04-08-2014. Conditions may change soon due to "us" accepting USD.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to avoid hurdles when using TOR is to put a VPN in front of TOR. E.g. if you use whonix as OS you have automatically everything routed via TOR. If you order then anonymously a VPN paid with crypto then the VPN doesn't know your id and the webpages don't discriminate you because they don't see that you use TOR. It only makes sense of course if you don't login this way into webpages who know your identity. You might use as well noscript or similar things because a user can easily be identified with data the browser reeals (language settings, OS version, browser version, screen resolution, windo resolution etc. etc.). Or better said they can recognize you on future visits (not necessarily knowing your id unless you use the same environment without TOR/VPN but same environmental data from your browser)

Answer (score -1):

[Hitbtc](http://hitbtc.com/) also allows to use it's services via TOR